# MySQL query counting many-to-many-relation slow on very large table (>10 mio. rows)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Please help me optimizing my query. It runs too slow on my sample tables (due to too many rows) and seems not feasible for online usage in a social network project of mine.

Background / motivation:

- I need to estimate, that I have several millions profiles. I therefore filled a sample table tbl_profile for 10 mio. users with random data.
- Each user can follow several interests. This is a many-to-many relationship between users (tbl_profile) and interests (tbl_interest), mapped through a table tbl_interest_subscription.

These are the tables:

First, my profile table **tbl_profile** (10.499.307 rows):

```
id            mediumint(8)
gender_id     tinyint(3)
weight        tinyint(3)
height        tinyint(3)
num_children  tinyint(3)
```

Now, the interest table **tbl_interest** (30 sample rows):

```
id            smallint(5)
owner_id      mediumint(8)
name          varchar(25)
```

Here, the mapping table between users and interests, **tbl_interest_subscription** (262.482.675 sample rows):

```
id            int(10)
profile_id    mediumint(8)
interest_id   smallint(5)
```

The table have further columns (e.g. timestamp of creation, etc.) which I do not show, because they only bloat the overview. If they should be of interest, I can of course show the complete tables.

My query has the following aim: Find those users, that fit my preferences (in height, weight, number of children, ...) and share my interests. And sort the results by the number of interests they have in common with me. 
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT map.profile_id, COUNT(map.interest_id) as num_matches_interests
FROM tbl_interest_subscription map

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT id
FROM tbl_profile
WHERE weight>=60 AND weight<=90
      AND height>=120 AND height<=190
      AND num_children=1
) AS profile ON profile.id=map.profile_id

WHERE map.interest_id IN (24, 25, 26, 27, 28)
GROUP BY map.profile_id
ORDER BY num_matches_interests DESC
LIMIT 20
```

The results from an EXPLAIN-call are these:

```
id: 1
select_type: PRIMARY
table: <derived2>
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 2422568
Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
***************************************
id: 2
select_type: PRIMARY
table: map
type: ref
possible_keys: idx_profileID_interestID (unique), idx_profileID, idx_interestID
key: idx_profileID_interestID
key_len: 3
ref: profile.id
rows: 12
Extra: Using where; Using index
***************************************
id: 3
select_type: DERIVED
table: tbl_profile
type: range
possible_keys: idx_weight_height_children
key: idx_weight_height_children
key_len: 10
ref: NULL
rows: 5249710
Extra: Using where; Using index
```

The query itself runs for ages (several minutes) on a Cloud-server @Digital Ocean with 2GB RAM, 2 CPUs (2,4 GHz each).

I reckon that the temporary table and filesort are the main problem, since I am already using indexes. I don't know however, how to avoid this, since I need the sorting of the counted interest shares and cannot sort an already given index.
On my search for optimiziation strategies I always read about partitioning, but I don't know how I should partition my interest mapping table beneficially.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Asked to run

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT map.profile_id, map.num_matches_interests 
FROM tbl_profile AS profile

INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT profile_id, COUNT(interest_id) AS num_matches_interests 
   FROM tbl_interest_subscription 
   WHERE interest_id IN ( 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 ) 
   GROUP BY profile_id) AS map ON profile.id=map.profile_id 

WHERE profile.weight BETWEEN 60 AND 90 
AND profile.height BETWEEN 120 AND 190 
AND profile.num_children=1
```

this is the result:

```
id: 1
select_type: PRIMARY
table: <derived2>
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 10.499.307
filtered: 100.00
Extra:
******************
id: 2
select_type: PRIMARY
table: profile
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY, idx_id_weight_height, idx_weight_height_numchildren
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 3
ref: map.profile_id
rows: 1
filtered: 100.00
Extra: Using where
******************
id: 3
select_type: DERIVED
table: tbl_interest_subscription
type: index
possible_keys: interest_id
key: idx_profile_interest
key_len: 5
ref: NULL
rows: 262.483.161
filtered: 36.75
Extra: Using where; Using index
```

The EXPLAIN-query ran for about 2-3 minutes.

Comment: What happens if you run the following: SELECT map.profile_id, count(*) FROM tbl_interest_subscription map WHERE map.interest_id IN (24, 25, 26, 27, 28) GROUP BY map.profile_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1.  I think you may have multiple profile_id's in tbl_interest_subscription that fit HERE map.interest_id IN (24, 25, 26, 27, 28). If so, you'll probably want to dedup those profile ids prior to joining with tbl_profile. Not sure if that's the case... but I suspect it is.

Comment: If I run your query, I get MySQL error #1064, stating, that I have an error in my query. If I run "SELECT map.profile_id, COUNT(*) FROM tbl_interest_subscription map WHERE map.interest_id IN (24, 25, 26, 27, 28) GROUP BY map.profile_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1" the query runs fine and returns after several minutes, with 10.499.307 rows, saying, that the query itself took 0.02sec.).

Comment: But I get the same amount of rows here, as when I reduce my original query to lose the inner joint: "SELECT map.profile_id, COUNT(map.interest_id) as num_matches_interests
FROM tbl_interest_subscription map
WHERE map.interest_id IN (24, 25, 26, 27, 28)
GROUP BY map.profile_id".

Thank you for your response, but I don't understand your concern. Of course I get multiple profile ids matching the WHERE...IN-clause, but I thought grouping them by their corresponding profile ids collapses them to one final row, which is then joined with the other table?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the problem lies also in the long loading time, to load all rows in order to be able to sort them. But how can I avoid this?

Comment: The error in my query is the count() instead of count(*). Inre: "Of course I get multiple profile ids matching..."  Exactly. That's my point. Every last one of those ids is going to be joined to profile. Say you have 5 rows for a given id in tbl_interest_subscription. Suppose the profile ids are unique in tbl_profile . Your join will produce 5 rows again, and the group by has to handle five times as much data as it needs. You need to dedup your profile ids in tbl_interest_subscription before joining. Try a subquery that aggregates count(interest_id) by profile before joining to profile.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
SELECT t1.profile_id, t1.num_matches_interests
FROM (
SELECT profile_id, COUNT(interest_id) AS num_matches_interests
FROM tbl_interest_subscription map
WHERE interest_id IN ( 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 ) 
GROUP BY profile_id
HAVING num_matches_interests >=1
)t1
ORDER BY num_matches_interests DESC 
LIMIT 20

EXPLAIN already takes 2-3 minutes for this aggregation (if I did it correctly).

Comment: Please run this and post above: EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT map.profile_id, map.num_matches_interests 
FROM tbl_profile AS profile
INNER JOIN (SELECT profile_id, 
COUNT(interest_id) AS num_matches_interests 
FROM tbl_interest_subscription 
WHERE interest_id IN ( 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 ) 
GROUP BY profile_id) AS map
ON profile.id=map.profile_id
WHERE profile.weight BETWEEN 60 AND 90
      AND profile.height BETWEEN 120 AND 190
      AND profile.num_children=1

Comment: Done. I appended it above.